# When to use accessor and when to access attribute directly?

Tags: objective-c

I have this piece of code in Objective-C taken from a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller):

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController_;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"details.closeDate" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                                               initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                               managedObjectContext:self.context
                                                               sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                               cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController_.delegate = self;

    [sort release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [theFetchedResultsController release];

    return fetchedResultsController_;
}
```

In my declaration file I have this:

```
@interface FailedBankListViewController : UITableViewController 

<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController_;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context_;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

@end
```

My question is why do I have to write the code like that, once we access directly the attribute, once we use the accessor:

```
if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController_;
}

// AND

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
```

and this doesn't work:

```
if (self.fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}

// AND

fetchedResultsController_ = theFetchedResultsController;
```

I don't understand when do I have to use the accessor and when do I have to use the accessor?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
```

is equivalent to calling

```
[self setFetchedResultsController:theFetchedResultsController];
```

Depending on the nature of the property, it is sometimes legitimate to bypass the setter method inside the class itself -- eg, in `dealloc` -- but most of the time you want to route all setting through that one method so that it can manage ownership and any other related admin tasks.

If you really wanted to access the ivar directly here, at a bare minimum you would need to ensure the object was `retain`-ed appropriately -- in the code shown you `release` it after setting. And it's quite possible there's other stuff happening in `setFetchedResultsController` as well. But without the code we can only guess. (For instance, I can't help thinking that the line setting `self` as delegate *should* be in the setter rather than here.)

Conversely, the line

```
 return self.fetchedResultsController;
```

is equivalent to calling

```
 return [self fetchedResultsController];
```

It should be obvious why the latter is a bad idea *inside* the `fetchedResultsController` method itself -- you wind up with an infinite regress.

Answer (score 0):

`accessor` are `setter` and `getter` methods for a property.
so when you make property then for setting and getting property values you need accessor methods(means setter and getter).

in code this line

```
self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
```

here a setter is called.