# On "self" and local accessors

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I always use accessors for instance variables in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519638/should-i-always-use-accessors-for-instance-variables-in-objective-c)

Lets suppose my `.h` file contains

```
Node *firstNode
```

Inside the `.m` file

What is the difference between

`[firstNode doSomething];` and

```
[[self firstNode] doSomething];
```

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164864/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271657/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332389/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088801/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494157/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519638/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753130/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[firstNode doSomething];` accesses the instance variable directly while `[[self firstNode] doSomething]` does not.

Which sounds very obvious, but a getter might do all manner of things, and its declaration can cause all manner of interesting things. Marking the accessor `retain` affects `firstNode`'s reference count, for instance, while Eimantas' answer tells us that a superclass (or subclass!) might change the precise meaning of `[self firstNode]`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have `@property` declared for `firstNode` instance variable, the former method does not use [potentially overridden] getter in your class.

Comment: So, assuming @property is declared, `[self firstNode]` serves no purpose? (The `self` part that is)

Comment: You can't call `[self firstNode]` if there is no property declared unless you have actual method `- (Node *)firstNode` declared and defined.